# Assigning `.txt` file contents to a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, variables, line

I am making an app that stores its settings in a `.txt` file. 
I am able to get the line count, but I don't know, how to store the different lines as values in a list.

For example:

```
linecount = 0
datainfile = [] 

with open("txt.txt" , "r") as t:
    linecount += 1

config1 = datainfile[0]
```

I have tried looking around on the internet, but could not find anything.

Comment: What is the problem here? Also, why do you wrap everything in a function that you don't call?

Comment: I do call it but the code is not in the example.

Comment: If you call it after this code snippet, configfile is already closed when the function aims to write. Do you need the function at all?

Comment: I put the file close part so people won't complain about how the file is always open. In my app I close it after the function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
lines = [] 
with open("txt.txt", "r") as t:
    for i in t:
        lines.append(t)
config1 = datainfile[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it is always a good practice to use context manager when opening a file (using the `with` keyword). Second, read the file to a list  and address the line number by index.

```
import os


with open("config.txt", "r") as cf:
    file_lines = [line.replace(os.linesep, "") for line in cf.readlines()]
```

Now each index in `file_lines` is relative to the line number in the file.